# Check if object is collection/iterable?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, collections

I have to initialize a collection of objects in constructor and I wanted to support all collection types, such as Arrays, Maps, and Sets. `typeof` will only return Object and there doesn't seem to be a generic `Collections` utility object that would provide a function like `Array.isArray()`.

Coming from Java and classical inheritance styles, my next impulse was to check the object's inheritance.  However, my experiments with various prototype functions didn't turn up anything.  The best I could figure out was to create a function that checks `.prototype.isPrototypeOf(object)` for Map, Set, and Array.  But that might be because I don't actually understand Javascripts prototypal inheritance.

Is there a better way to check if an object is a collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check whether it's `Iterable` instead:

```
function isIterable(obj) {
  if (obj == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
}
```

[MDN web docs - Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following hack, which should be supported by IE 11 and up:

```
if(typeof collection !== "undefined" && typeof collection.forEach !== "undefined"){
  collection.forEach(function(value, param2, collection){
    //do stuff
  }, this);
}
```

The `param2` is different for each collection type: for Arrays it is the index, for Maps it is the key, and Sets just repeats the same value so as to match the function signature of Maps and Arrays.

The `this` argument assigns the anonymous function's `this` to the outer function's `this` – enabling references to variables assigned in the outer function.  Otherwise it will default to the global `window`.

I would strongly prefer either a direct test of the object's inheritance or a standards based Collections.isCollection type object and will select a new answer.

Comment: You should check for `typeof collection == "object" && typeof collection.forEach == "function"` explicitly

Comment: and throw a null check in there too :p

Comment: Use `collection != null` instead of `typeof collection !== "undefined"` to check for both `null` and `undefined`.